# I have a problem importing xlrd in python

Tags: python, import, package, libraries, xlrd

Hi I'm trying to import this libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import xlrd
from datetime import date
```

When i run this code this erro appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [6] in <cell line: 6>
    import xlrd

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py:1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This code use top work but I don't know why is not working.

Comment: That's Python 2

Comment: In Python 3.0+ `print()` is a function, not a statement — so it looks like you have the Python 2 version of `xlrd` installed somehow.